# Find a User's SE Reputation

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

### Challenge

Given a SE user's ID, output the sum of their reputation from across all of the Stack Exchange networks​ the user has signed up to.

### Rules

If a user has 101 or less reputation on a site, count it as zero in the sum.

***You should not count Area 51 rep or hidden communities!!***

URL shorteners are disallowed.

### Examples

***Subject to change***

#### [User 3244989 (Beta Decay)](http://stackexchange.com/users/3244989/beta-decay)

```
14141
```

#### [User 918086 (Dennis)](http://stackexchange.com/users/918086/dennis)

```
204892
```

#### [User 11683 (Jon Skeet)](http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet)

```
1029180
```

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## curl, grep and awk, 106 bytes

```
curl http://api.stackexchange.com/users/$1/associated|grep -o n\"[^,]*|awk -F: '$2>101{s+=$2}END{print s}'
```

It's dirty but seems to work well. I don't use `awk` often so I wouldn't be surprised if there was a way to golf the `grep` away with it.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2 (with Requests), 149 Bytes

```
from requests import*
lambda i,r="reputation":sum(u[r]for u in get("http://api.stackexchange.com/users/"+i+"/associated").json()["items"]if u[r]>101)
```

I requested the API, converted the API to JSON, then summed the reputation via a generator expression.  The generator does remove accounts with less than 101 reputation.

Credit for improving the code: [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Answer (score 1):

## R with httr, 146 Bytes

```
library(httr)
a=sapply(content(GET(paste0("http://api.stackexchange.com/users/",readline(),"/associated")))$items,'[[','reputation')
sum(a[a>101])
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>148</s> <s>143</s> <s>142</s> 141 bytes

```
u=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/users/${u}/associated`).then(j=>j.json(s=0)).then(i=>(i.items.map(r=>s+=(r=r.reputation)>101&&r),alert(s)))
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=

u=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/users/${u}/associated`).then(j=>j.json(s=0)).then(i=>(i.items.map(r=>s+=(r=r.reputation)>101&&r),alert(s)))

i.addEventListener("submit",e=>{e.preventDefault();(v=+i.firstChild.value)&&f(v)})
```

```html
<form id=i><input type=number><button>Calc.</button></form>
```

Comment: Does this ignore Area 51?

Comment: @BetaDecay, I *think* so. I'm editing a caveat into my answer now to explain.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't think it'd be so simple to filter out

Comment: @BetaDecay, is that confirmation that that endpoint *doesn't* include A51 sites?

Comment: What do you mean by endpoint? :/

Comment: @BetaDecay, the API endpoint I'm using to retrieve a user's data. e.g., does http://api.stackexchange.com/users/918086/associated include A51 sites. From Neil's comnent on his answer, it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57550/discussion-between-beta-decay-and-shaggy).

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 2.4, 136 + 20 = 156 bytes

Requires the `-rjson -rnet/http -n` flags. Input is from STDIN (no trailing newline). Ruby 2.4 is needed for `sum`.

```
p JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get URI"http://api.stackexchange.com/users/#$_/associated")["items"].map{|i|i["reputation"]}.select{|i|i>101}.sum
```